# How can I get syntax highlighting to support multiline JavaScript strings?

Tags: syntax-highlighting, line-breaks, filetype-javascript

Currently I have JavaScript (.js) files that contain multiline strings. Vim's syntax highlighting does not seem to support these, as seen in the image below:
[image: Improper multiline syntax highlighting]

Anything below the first line is not properly recognized as a string, and everything after the end quote is incorrectly considered a string. Any way to fix this?

Comment: I know this doesn't answer your question, but your choice of string formatting is usually discouraged in javascript. See http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javascriptguide.xml?showone=Multiline_string_literals#Multiline_string_literals for reference and a way to avoid this problem.

Comment: Yeah my main reason for this format was that I'm not very good at SQL, so when I run into issues I copy and paste the SQL into a MySQL client to test things, and then when I've figured it out I put it back in my project. I found this syntax the easiest to convert to a single line of SQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `/usr/share/vim/vim74/syntax/javascript.vim` uses this to define what a "string region" is in Javascript:

```
syn region javaScriptStringD start=+"+ skip=+\\\\\|\\"+ end=+"\|$+ contains=javaScriptSpecial,@htmlPreproc
```

The `end` option matches either the `"` character, *or* the end of the line `$`, which is why the syntax highlighting stops after the first line.

We can override this by making a `~/.vim/after/syntax/javascript.vim` file with:

```
syn region javaScriptStringD start=+"+ skip=+\\\\\|\\"+ end=+"+ contains=javaScriptSpecial,@htmlPreproc
syn region javaScriptStringS start=+'+ skip=+\\\\\|\\'+ end=+'+ contains=javaScriptSpecial,@htmlPreproc
```

One line for `"strings"`, and another for `'strings'`. We just removed the `|$` part (`|` for "or", `$` for end of line).

Note: I think it would be better to *only* highlight the string if the previous line escapes the `\n` (ie. ends with `\`). I happen to know that the C syntax does this, but I can't seem to <s>steal</s> borrow that and get it working in Javascript :-/